# What would be the quotient groups $U_{\mathrm{gen}}/U_{\mathrm{gen}}^{(n)}$ and $U_{\mathrm{gen}}^{(n)}/U_{\mathrm{gen}}^{(n+1)}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings, p-adic-numbers

Let $K \supseteq \mathbb{Q}_p$ be a $p$-adic field with ring of integer $O$ and maximal ideal $m$. Let $O^*$ be the group of units in $O$.

Consider the group of units $U^{(0)}=U=O^*$ and $U^{(n)}=1+m^n=\{u \in O^* : u- 1 \in m^n \}$.

Then we have the decreasing filter $$O^* \supseteq U^{(1)} \supseteq U^{(2)} \supseteq \cdots,$$ whose quotients
are given by the following isomorphisms $$ U/U^{(n)} \cong (O/m^n)^* \ \text{and} \ U^{(n)}/U^{(n+1)} \cong O/m, \ ...........(1)$$
I have question regarding generalization of these facts.

**Generalisation:**

Let us denote $ID_r(O^*)$ to be set of all $r \times r$ **invertible** as well as **diagonal** matrices with entries in $O^*$; and consider the following sets $$U_{\mathrm{gen}}^{(n)}=\{u \in ID_r(O^*) : u- \text{Id} \in ID_r(m^n) \}, \ \text{Id  is the identity matrix}.$$ Here every element $u=\text{diag}(u_1,~u_2, \cdots,u_r) \in U_{\mathrm{gen}}^{(n)}$ are diagonal matrix.

Then clearly $U_{\mathrm{gen}}^{(n)} $ forms an **abelian** group of $ID_r(O^*)$.  Because, if $u=\mathrm{diag}(u_1,~u_2, \cdots,u_r)$ and  $v=\mathrm{diag}(v_1,~v_2, \cdots,v_r)$ in $U_{\mathrm{gen}}^{(n)}$, then $uv=\mathrm{diag}(u_1v_1,~u_2v_2, \cdots,u_rv_r) \in U_{\mathrm{gen}}^{(n)}$ and the inverse of $u=\mathrm{diag}(u_1,~u_2, \cdots,u_r)$ exists. $U_{\mathrm{gen}}^{(n)}$ is abelian because two diagonal matrices commutes $(uv=vu$).

Now define $U_{\mathrm{gen}}^{(0)}=U_{\mathrm{gen}}=ID_r(O^*)$. Here also we have similar  decreasing filtration $$ ID_r(O^*)=U_{gen} \supseteq U_{\mathrm{gen}}^{(1)} \supseteq U_{\mathrm{gen}}^{(2)} \supseteq \cdots.$$ **Questions:**

$(1)$ What would be the quotient groups $U_{\mathrm{gen}}/U_{\mathrm{gen}}^{(n)}$  and $U_{\mathrm{gen}}^{(n)}/U_{\mathrm{gen}}^{(n+1)}$ ?

$(2)$  Do we have same isomorphisms as in equation $(1)$ above ?

Comment: $U_{\text{gen}}^{(n)}$ is just $(U^{(n)})^r$.  (So, (1) the quotients are the $r$-fold copies of the original quotients, and (2) yes, componentwise.)

Comment: @LSpice, Thanks. So we have $U_{\mathrm{gen}}^{(n)}=\oplus_{r \ Copies} U^{(n)}$.  Hence $U_{\mathrm{gen}}/U_{\mathrm{gen}}^{(n)} \cong \oplus_{r \ Copies} \left( O/m^n \right)^{*}$ and $U_{\mathrm{gen}}^{(n)}/U_{\mathrm{gen}}^{(n+1)} \cong \oplus_{r \ Copies} O/m $. Is it ?

Comment: Yes, [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371549/what-would-be-the-quotient-groups-u-mathrmgen-u-mathrmgenn-and#comment939573_371549)'s right.